# httpServer to execute PHP script

Tags: java, php, httpserver, java-server

I am writing a java http server and I have completed FileServer class to handle requests (Get, Head, Post, etc) for normal files like index.hitml
I also want to enable my server to execute PHP scripts and return the output to clients.
     "http://localhost/phpinfo.php "

How can I do that? I need some resources.
Please point me to any resources or apis to read :)
Thanks

Comment: You're going to want to read up on using PHP as a command-line application ( [unix](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/install.unix.commandline.php), [windows](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/install.windows.commandline.php) ).

Comment: If you are writing a java web server that can run PHP, it's already been done. It's called [Quercus](http://www.caucho.com/resin-3.1/doc/quercus.xtp).

Answer (score 0):

The least painful to write way to do this is also the most painful to run: CGI. This involves nothing more than setting a few environment variables and running the PHP interpreter.

A better way would be to implement an FCGI client, that (starts and) connects to one of the many existing FCGI wrappers for PHP.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to accomplish is to just call a PHP interpreter from java (via `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()`. You could just use take the output the PHP interpreter generates and send it to the browser. However, when called like this, PHP is run in the so called "Command Line Interface" mode, which behaves differently compared to the standard CGI mode (especially when it comes to reading the script argument, the http request etc.)

A better approach might be using fastCGI. Look at this page on how to spawn PHP as fast cgi process: http://wiki.nginx.org/PHPFcgiExample (linux)

In your server, you need to implement the fast cgi protocol, which can be found here: http://www.fastcgi.com/devkit/doc/fcgi-spec.html

Answer (score 0):

after php version 5.4 , php(cli) has build-in web-server command `-S`

```
--server addr:port
-S addr:port   # Start embedded Webserver on the given local address and port
```

example : listen 8080 ports for all incoming trafic

`php -S 0.0.0.0:8080 <target_file|dictionary>`